# Decoding a time format

Tags: binary-format

I'm reverse engineering a hardware device which stores time a strange format:

| 32-bit word | H:MM:SS (rounded) |
| --- | --- |
| 0x03200000 | 0:00:00 |
| 0x09700000 | 0:00:00 |
| 0x0A1B0000 | 0:00:01 |
| 0x0A160000 | 0:00:01 |
| 0x0B098000 | 0:00:02 |
| 0x0F376600 | 0:00:46 |
| 0x0F347800 | 0:00:46 |
| 0x10038B00 | 0:01:07 |
| 0x10040800 | 0:01:07 |
| 0x1056A600 | 0:01:49 |
| 0x10573C00 | 0:01:50 |
| 0x10589A00 | 0:01:50 |
| 0x1058B300 | 0:01:50 |
| 0x13173240 | 0:10:19 |
| 0x13173880 | 0:10:19 |

I believe the time is recorded in some internal high-frequency timer ticks, but I don't see any linear correspondence between the words and time values. Any tips?

UPD. I found out that it's Texas Instruments's custom floating-point format for TMS320 DSPs. Described [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spra400).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values appear to be a floating point format similar to [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

If I interpret the first byte as an unbiased exponent and interpret the other bytes (excluding the highest bit) as a fraction, then the value <kbd>(1 + *fraction*) × 2<sup>*exponent*</sup></kbd> appears to be the number of milliseconds:

[image: table showing how the bits are assigned to exponent and fraction values]

Equivalently, in the following textual table, the first byte ***e*** is the exponent, the other bytes ***n*** form the numerator of the fraction, and the denominator of the fraction is 2<sup>23</sup>. The value <kbd>(1 + *n*/2<sup>23</sup>) × 2<sup>*e*</sup></kbd> is the number of milliseconds:

| *e* | *n* | *e* | *n* | (1 + *n*/2<sup>23</sup>) × 2<sup>*e*</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `03` | `200000` | 3 | 2097152 | 10 |
| `09` | `700000` | 9 | 7340032 | 960 |
| `0A` | `1B0000` | 10 | 1769472 | 1240 |
| `0A` | `160000` | 10 | 1441792 | 1200 |
| `0B` | `098000` | 11 | 622592 | 2200 |
| `0F` | `376600` | 15 | 3630592 | 46950 |
| `0F` | `347800` | 15 | 3438592 | 46200 |
| `10` | `038B00` | 16 | 232192 | 67350 |
| `10` | `040800` | 16 | 264192 | 67600 |
| `10` | `56A600` | 16 | 5678592 | 109900 |
| `10` | `573C00` | 16 | 5716992 | 110200 |
| `10` | `589A00` | 16 | 5806592 | 110900 |
| `10` | `58B300` | 16 | 5812992 | 110950 |
| `13` | `173240` | 19 | 1520192 | 619300 |
| `13` | `173880` | 19 | 1521792 | 619400 |